# Kubernetes Ingress whitelist-source-range Allow all IPs

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am setting an IP whitelist in my kubernetes ingress config via the annotation `ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range`. But, I have different whitelists to apply for different environments (`dev`, `staging`, `production`, etc.) Therefore, I have a placeholder variable in my `deploy.yaml` that I find/replace with the appropriate IP whitelist based on the environment.

At the moment, for dev, I am passing an empty string as the whitelist because it should be able to receive traffic from all IPs, which currently works as intended. But, logs in `nginx-ingress-controller` complain about the following:

```
error reading Whitelist annotation in Ingress default/{service}: the 
annotation does not contain a valid IP address or network: invalid CIDR 
address:
```

How do I set a proper `whitelist-source-range` to allow all IPs but not create noisy error logs like the one above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will give you error reading according to the [ingress annotations ip whitelist](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/internal/ingress/annotations/ipwhitelist/main_test.go).
It suspecting a IP range or Multiple IP ranges, even you didn't put a value, you will get the reading error as well, to get ride of this error and allow all the IPs put 0.0.0.0/0 this will bypass and fix your issue.

Comment: According to this documentation: https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/kubernetes/, "all source IPs are permitted if the list is empty or a single range is ill-formatted", so I was unsure why it complained. Why does 0.0.0.0/0 satisfy all IPs? both v4 and v6? @Alioua

Comment: 0.0.0.0/0 satisfy all IPs, and its valid when the parsing begin, the only valid value is you whatever IP or Range since the function is expecting that. If you let even empty it will trow an error "the annotation does not contain a valid IP address or network: invalid CIDR address: "